# timeout method can't break executing in Completable.fromAction()

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I discovered an error with method `.timeout()` in `Completable`, created by method `.fromAction()`:

```
    Completable.fromAction(() -> {
        System.out.println("start time: " + timeString());
        Thread.sleep(10_000);
    })
            .timeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .onErrorComplete()
            .blockingAwait();

    System.out.println("after time: " + timeString());
```

Code inside the brackets executes 10 seconds, timeout set on 3 seconds. However, executing finishes only after 10 seconds. This is output of program:

```
start time: 14:55
after time: 15:05

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

**Question**: why executing breaks not after 3 seconds and how to fix it?

Comment: Try `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` after `fromAction`.

Comment: @akarnokd, hah, works fine! :) But why?

Comment: `timeout` can't interrupt the main thread but it can interrupt tasks running on a `Scheduler`.

Comment: @akarnokd, write it in answer, please. I will accept it. And thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` after `fromAction`. `timeout` can't interrupt the main thread but it can interrupt tasks running on a `Scheduler`.